# What is the legend behind Siddhivinayak?

Tags: puranas, ganesha, ashtavinayak

The [Siddhivinayak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ashtavinayaka#Siddhivinayak) temple at Siddatek, is one of the Ashtavinayak temples. The linked wikipedia page mentions that

> God Vishnu is supposed to have vanquished the asuras Madhu and Kaitabh after propitiating Ganesha here.
>   This is the only murti of these eight with the trunk positioned to the right.

Similarly, [the government website of Siddhivinayak, Siddatek](http://ahmednagar.gov.in/html_docs/..%5Chtml_docs%5CSiddhtek.htm), mentions this legend  of  Siddhivinayak with a bit more detail and ends with

> Lord Vishnu, sage Vyas, sage Bhrushundi, sage Moraya Gosavi, sage Narayan Maharaj were stayed at this holy place. This place is one of the twenty-one places of Lord Ganesha, which mentioned in the purana (mythology).

The question is, in which religious text has the legend of Siddhivinayak (about both Lord Vishnu's conquest of Madhu-Kaitabh) been mentioned and what are the verses which speak about him?

Comment: It's probably mentioned in either the Ganesha Purana or the Mudgala Purana, but both of those are considered very late texts.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to check in them. Unfortunately an English translation of either of them is not available online.

Comment: This story is referenced in Chapter 18 of Upasanakhanda of Ganesha Purana as per my [answer here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19914/did-lord-vishnu-pray-to-lord-ganesha-if-yes-in-which-scripture-is-it-written/21545#21545). (Unfortunately, only parts of the English version of Ganesha Purana are available in the Google Books section. But you can still get to read most of the story)